# Apache Kafka Java Client Compatibility with Java 17

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, java-17

I am using AWS MSK cluster with Kafka version 2.6.2 and my kafka client version is 2.7.0. Both are currently working fine. Now i need to upgrade my applications to Java 17. Do i need to upgrade my java kafka client version to be compatible with Java 17 or can i use the same Java client version with Java 17? I have seen here https://kafka.apache.org/downloads 3.1.0 is the Kafka version that supports Java 17 but i cannot upgrade the Kafka Version in MSK at the moment. My only need is to upgrade the application only to Java 17 with minimal code changes. kafka-streams and kafka-clients are used in my application

Comment: If you only upgrade your application to Java 17, then there should't be any issues. The Kafka Client is just a library that was compiled (probably) with Java 8. You should be able to use oder the library without issue when you upgrade the application runtime version (unless some major changes were introduced, like the removal of `javax` after JDK 8 that the code depends upon etc)

Comment: You should upgrade to the newest client anyway... 2.7 is very old... And yes, newer clients are backward compatible to older brokers.